# Is storing product information as strings acceptable in OrderLines?

Tags: mysql

When a user makes a order I create a `Order`-object with the following data:

```
+-----------+
|   Order   |
+-----------+
| ID        |
| user      |
| vendor    |
| timestamp |
| ...       |
+-----------+
```

For each product the user has ordered a `OrderLine` is linked to the `Order`.

```
+---------------------------+
|         OrderLine         |
+---------------------------+
| ID                        |
| order_id (FK)             |
| product_id (FK)           |
| quantity                  |
| price_on_time_of_purchase |
+---------------------------+
```

This way I can keep a history for each user of what products he has ordered, and display that history in his purchase-overview.

But in the catalog, products can be updated or totally removed from the database. So if a user would purchase a product with ID 123 and that product gets deleted later, the information (name, description,...) of product 123 cannot be displayed in the users' overview anymore.

A solution would be to only "soft delete" products, so the information of all products would remain accessible at all times.

But, would it also be reasonable to not store the ID's of products in `OrderLine` but rather the product's name and description as a string?

So instead of doing

```
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+---------------------------+
| OrderLine |          |            |          |                           |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+---------------------------+
| ID        | order_id | product_id | quantity | price_on_time_of_purchase |
| 1         | 5        | 3          | 5        | 3.25                      |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+---------------------------+
```

I would do

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------------+
| OrderLine |          |                             |          |                           |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------------+
| ID        | order_id | product                     | quantity | price_on_time_of_purchase |
| 1         | 5        | My Product with description | 5        | 3.25                      |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------------+
```

This way I can keep showing the user an accurate history of his purchases at all time, without keeping a history of all the products.

So... Is storing product-information (name, description,...) as a string in `OrderLine`s acceptable. Or should I stick to storing ID's and soft-deleting?

Comment: *A solution would be to only "soft delete" products* This is not a solution. The product properties may be altered, which will alter the data in all existing orders lines.

Comment: @Akina I’ll make the properties of Product non-updatable. Only the price will be updatable. But the actual price is stored in the OrderLine each time.

Comment: *I’ll make the properties of Product non-updatable.* Something will definitely make you change that.. it is more safe to take this possibility into account before it occures.

Comment: @Akina So you'd highly advise to make a separate table to track the updated attributes of each product? Seems reasonable. But isn't the easier solution to soft-delete and create a new row each time a product is updated?

Comment: The solution with soft-delete may produce the rows which are used in none purchase if there was not a sale between two row editions. This is not a problem, of course.. From the other side for soft-delete solution you must add actuality column and refer to it in any query while creating an order.. I don't know does this solution is more easy.

Comment: @Akina Yeah so that means that I could be having rows which would never be used in a sale, but that’s the same in a update-history-tracking-table. I will implement one of the two solutions (update-tracking table of products OR soft-delete at every update). Still in doubt, thanks!

Comment: Additionally - take into account that the order may be approved by its creator or not approved yet..

Comment: "Without keeping a history of all the products" - this isn't a big imposition in a database.  You should already be storing this, not necessarily for `OrderLine`, but in general to maintain what information may have been displayed to a customer or salesperson.  Also, `Products` cannot be deleted if they've ever been sold, ordered, or otherwise involved in some business transaction - they can only be made inactive.  So store the status of the `Product` and a history of all material changes in an audit table `ProductHistory` - if you need the description at the time of sale it will be there.

Answer (score 1):

Storing extra information here is denormalization. You risk data inconsistencies once you does this: You need to update those name, descriptions in this table when they're updated in another table.

imo in your use case, soft-deleting is a better idea

Comment: How can there be data inconsistency when the only use-case of an `OrderLine` is to store the information of the product relevant on the given timestamp? Isn't 'inconsistency' not what we are trying to achieve in this specific scenario?

Comment: Because I do NOT need to update the product-name when updated. I need to show the user the exact product-name and -description which it was on the time he ordered the product.

Comment: @O'Niel What if there was an error in the `ProductName`, such as a typo?...by storing it in multiple tables, you need to remember to update multiple tables to fix it, which is more error prone and less efficient. You're better off storing the `ProductId` when they need to be deleted instead, and soft-deleting the `Products` like this answer suggests

Comment: @J.D. But that also means that for every time a product gets updated (e.g the admin gives it a different name), I need to store the original product (before update) in a different row and give it the label `is_deleted` == `true`? Imagine buying a product named "Apples", and the admin renames it to "Oranges". In your purchase history the user still needs to see "Apples". So, tl;dr: Not only deletes, but also updates need to have a soft-delete?

Comment: @O'Niel "*Imagine buying a product named "Apples", and the admin renames it to "Oranges"*" - That would never happen in a logically designed system because those are two different products. It would not be correct to update `Apples` to `Oranges`. Similarly in your system, a different product should be a new `INSERT` into the `Products` table, not an `UPDATE` to an existing product.

Comment: @J.D. Okay, what if there is a product with ID 123 named "Apples" listed for €5. And a user purchases it. Then the admin updates the price of product 123 to €7. The user still needs to see €5 in his purchase history. But if I'd reference by ID instead of copying the data to string, I'd get €7. Or do you suggest to copy only the original price in the orderline, and reference all the other data (name, description,...) by ID?

Comment: @O'Niel That's a slightly different question. Typically `Price` is a field stored on an `OrderLine` in addition to `Quantity` as these are attributes specific to `OrderLine`. It generally should not be stored in the `Products` table. Any other kinds of attributes that would be stored in the `Product` table that are liable to change and you needed the history on, you would have a separate `ProductHistory` table to log to, or you would implement a change tracking feature of the database system you're using.

Comment: @J.D. Alright, I think I get it... I will store `price` and `quantity` in `OrderLine` to have the actual price on time of purchase. And in `OrderLine` I will reference the product by ID. The attributes of `Product` (name, description,...) will be non-updatable.

Comment: *Storing extra information here is denormalization* - it is not (by default) denormalization if it is stored for a specific reason - the same way sales price and other attributes necessary for legal reasons are stored.  Given the nature of the problem it's maybe not the best solution, but it is not denormalization the same way bank statements and recording sales price are not denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the catalog, products can be updated or totally removed from the database.

If so then the product in the `products` table is a pattern and not an entity. I.e. you must not refer to it but copy its data into the order line. The pattern instance (in `products`) and the entity instance (in `order_lines`) are not related.

But this de-normalizes the data.

As a solution you may create additional table `products_in_orders`, copy current product into it (if it is not present yet in current state - test all columns values, or test `product_id` and `product_state_timestamp`), and refer `product_id` to this table instead of `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

Strings and JSON are ok for storing information that will not need to be parsed and used in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause.

Likewise, numbers and dates should not be stored in `VARCHARs`.

`INDEXes` are the key to performance; they can only work on values they can get to.

For "small" databases this advise does not matter; for large datasets, it can matter a lot.